# combine the CSS files and minfie in PHP ( wordpress )

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hello I have worked on many projects and I have this Question ...

all of us know in Wordpress its better to combine all CSS files in One
but on other hand
there is post page use CSS that is never used in main page
category page use CSS never used in main or post page .

**normally I dived the the CSS into files**
I will give you example for easy understanding .

`style.css` ( contain all shared and basic CSS )

`main.css` ( main page )

`category.css`

`page.css`

`vote.css` ( for vote block it used in main + single page )

`blockStyle1.css` ( style for one block it used in main + categories )

`....`

**I end up for category page to call**

`style.css`

`category.css`

`blockstyle1.css`

`....`

.
.

**what I try to accomplish is in category for example this 3 files on run time
will be combined together in 1 file**

so I will keep my divided files idea + minimize the request to server .

Comment: I need to do this in CLEAN PHP I dont want to use plugin that I dont know what to do and lack the performance of my project

Comment: How big are the files? minified version.

Comment: you mean all of them ?? in one theme WP primium them they are around 400KB ,,, in other news website they are around 250KB in other website sport website with many pages around 340KB

Comment: you mean to combine them all any why ? in web pages if we save 20KB its great then how about 100 or 200 KB ? this cause the project to become worse and worse when it grows . you get my point ?

Comment: Saving on data is important for sure. Using minified versions of all css and including only necessary on each page would do the trick. To further improve performance you could enable caching on server so that it will save subsequent requests to server.

Comment: I am aready doing this using cascade + atomic CSS + reusable general classes ... about combining the files I was imagin some way like function I pass the names of the files I need and it will combine for each file .... function or some way ... I dont know

Comment: Thats interesting. I am not sure if it is possible at run time but would like to know if there is a way. So far all I could think of is to use minified versions and enabling caching. That way request would be made only once from client.

Comment: Exactly !!! I think its mostly a lack in WordPress

Comment: google pagespeed module

Answer (score 1):

Grunt is your answer. Grunt is a task manager versatile for every need. In your case, it is there waiting for changes to your style sheets, and when the file is saved, it will merge them into one file, minimizing it.

How implement Grunt?
It's simple:

For first, install Grunt in your machine and create a project as explained in this page: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Now let's create your Gruntfile.js with appropriate contribs (http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile)

The Gruntfile.js for you project should be the seguent:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {
            dist: {
                src: ['css/*.css'],
                dest: 'style.css'
            }
        },

        watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['css/*.css'],
                tasks: ['concat']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

By command line launch `grunt` in your project directory and do your style changes.

P.S. What you think about using Sass? Learn about http://sass-lang.com/ , http://compass-style.org/ and https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass

Comment: I know about Grunt and I have use it .... but your grunt will concat all the CSS into 1 this is not what I am looking for I want to contact all the CSS related to category page into 1 then call them from category page 
( category page dont call all the CSS in my project it calls some of them  )
also I thought of the idea of put each group of css in one folder like this is categories folder and contact them but it will not work because some files like the vote block will be called for many pages ...

Comment: we can make like grunt to watch group of files for categories watch [ 1 2 3 ] and concat them in categoy.css and so category will call this file only and so on post watch [ 1 4 5 ] and main page watch [ 1 2 6 ] ... so we will move the logic of the concatenation from php to grunt and will cause less process for the server ... but I think the PHP option is better for easy devlopment

Comment: about the less and sass how it will help with this can you explain ...?? less & saas generate long selectors and this is bad practice .

Answer (score -3):

Simple you can use **Better WordPress Minify** Wordpress Plugin..

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/installation/

Comment: its possible but I need more clean solution to do this combination maybe we can get the CSS minify code and edit it for this advance minify